# How to build snappy on windows 10 in VS2015?

Tags: c++, compression, snappy

I hava download snappy 1.1.8 on [here](https://github.com/google/snappy),and follow the readme to compile on my computer,

> mkdir build
>
> cd build && cmake ../

then I open the `.sln` file in VS2015,build the `lib`,there are no errors.

then I write an example like below,and add the `lib` to my project:

```
class Sna
{
public:
    Sna(string &data) :data_(data)
    {
    }

    void compress()
    {
        auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
        snappy::Compress(data_.data(), data_.size(), &compressed_);

        auto end = high_resolution_clock::now();
        cout << "compress use time: " << duration_cast<microseconds>(end - start).count() << " microseconds" << endl;
    }

    void unCompress()
    {
        auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
        snappy::Uncompress(compressed_.data(),compressed_.size(),&recoverd_);
        auto end = high_resolution_clock::now();
        cout << "unCompress use time: " << duration_cast<microseconds>(end - start).count() << " microseconds" << endl;
    }

    bool check()
    {
        return !data_.compare(recoverd_) ? true : false;
    }

    double ratio()
    {
        int temp = int(data_.length() - compressed_.length());
        double d = (double)temp / data_.length();
        return d * 100;
    }

private:
    string data_, compressed_, recoverd_;
};

int main()
{
    //read data from file
    //...

    Sna sna(data);
    sna.compress();
    sna.unCompress();

    return 0;
}
```

the `compress` function is ok,but when execute the `unCompress` function,the program crashed,it gave me this error:

> 0xC000001D: Illegal Instruction。

on `snappy.cc` line 720:

```
 #if SNAPPY_HAVE_BMI2
  return _bzhi_u32(v, 8 * n);
```

I have tried:

1. fallback the version of snappy 1.1.7,it works well for me,don't have this problem.
2. when compile the lib,set the `Enable Enhanced Instruction Set` to `Advanced Vector Extensions 2 (/arch:AVX2)`,but it still had other problems.

I don't know which step I did wrong? and how to solve this problem?

Comment: Your machine doesn't support the BMI2 instruction set. Find the cmake configuration option SNAPPY_HAVE_BMI2 and disable it.

Comment: rpress You should probably make an answer.

Comment: @rpress thank you for helped me solved this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @rpress, solved this problem.

found the file `CMakeLists.txt`.and comment out the line 118 to 112 like below

```
# check_cxx_source_compiles("
# #include <immintrin.h>
# int main() {
#   return _bzhi_u32(0, 1);
# }" SNAPPY_HAVE_BMI2)
```